# Testing React form onSubmit with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a very simple form component which expects an `onSubmit` handler.

```
const NoteForm = ({ handleNoteOnSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleNoteOnSubmit}>
    <input name="note" id="note" />
    <button type="submit">save</button>
  </form>
);

export default NoteForm;
```

The `onSubmit` handler looks like this.

```
  const handleNoteSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const noteObject = {
      content: event.target.note.value
    };

    // save note here....
  };
```

In my test, I want to assert that when I submit my form, the handler receives the data I submit.

```
describe('NoteForm', () => {
  test('<NoteForm /> calls onSubmit', async () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
    const { container } = render(
      <NoteForm handleNoteOnSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    );

    const noteInput = container.querySelector('input[name="note"]');
    fireEvent.change(noteInput, {
      target: { name: 'note', value: 'testing a form...' },
    });

    fireEvent.submit(container.querySelector('form'));
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        target: { note: { value: 'testing a form...' } },
      })
    );
  });
});
```

Instead, my handler receives a `SyntheticBaseEvent`, which contains the following:

```
    + SyntheticBaseEvent {
    +   "_reactName": "onSubmit",
    +   "_targetInst": null,
    +   "bubbles": true,
    +   "cancelable": true,
    +   "currentTarget": null,
    +   "defaultPrevented": false,
    +   "eventPhase": 3,
    +   "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
    +   "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
    +   "isTrusted": true,
    +   "nativeEvent": Event {
    +     "isTrusted": true,
    +   },
    +   "target": <form>
    +     <input
    +       id="note"
    +       name="note"
    +     />
    +     <button
    +       type="submit"
    +     >
    +       save
    +     </button>
    +   </form>,
    +   "timeStamp": 1679044636947,
    +   "type": "submit",
      },
```

I have looked at similar questions and everywhere it seems to do take a similar approach, here and there with some different forms of expect. But in every case, I always have this `SyntheticBaseEvent` which doesn't seem to contain my form data.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) to access the form control - the `input` element in your case.

`e.target` is the `form` element, so if you want to get the value of the `input` element, you should access the `e.target.elements.note.value` property.

We should call `e.presist()` in our mock `handleSubmit` event handler to avoid the below warning:

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `isDefaultPrevented` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use `event.persist()`.

At last, the `e`, `e.target`, `e.target.elements`, and `e.target.elements.note` objects, each of it do not just contain one property, so we should use [`expect.objectContaining()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectobjectcontainingobject) to match **subset** of these objects.

E.g.

`note-form.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";

const NoteForm = ({ handleNoteOnSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleNoteOnSubmit}>
    <input name="note" id="note" />
    <button type="submit">save</button>
  </form>
);

export default NoteForm;
```

`note-form.test.jsx`:

```
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import NoteForm from './note-form';

describe('NoteForm', () => {
  test('<NoteForm /> calls onSubmit', async () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn().mockImplementation((e) => {
      e.persist();
    });
    const { container } = render(<NoteForm handleNoteOnSubmit={handleSubmit} />);

    const noteInput = container.querySelector('input[name="note"]');
    fireEvent.change(noteInput, {
      target: { name: 'note', value: 'testing a form...' },
    });

    fireEvent.submit(container.querySelector('form'));
    expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.objectContaining({
        target: expect.objectContaining({
          elements: expect.objectContaining({ note: expect.objectContaining({ value: 'testing a form...' }) }),
        }),
      })
    );
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75766171/note-form.test.jsx (7.2 s)
  NoteForm
    ✓ <NoteForm /> calls onSubmit (24 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 note-form.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        7.493 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"react": "^16.14.0",
```